# Button being sent automatically?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I need this button to be automatically "pressed" when entering the site, or after X seconds.

```
    <button id='settingsTab' class='all'>||</button>
    <div id='settingsContainer'>
      <div id='channelInput' style='position:absolute;top:15px;font-size:0;width:330px;'>
        <input type="text" id="channel" style='width:215px;' name="channel" value='sodapoppin'>
        <button id='join'>Join</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Is this possible, having the "join" button being sent by just entering the site?

Also, im pretty new to this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Is this possible, having the "join" button being sent by just entering the site?
```

yes it is possible. 
You will have to use the `setTimeout` function of `javascript` or `Jquery` to achieve this. Also wrap your code in a document ready function so that it executes only when the document has been fully loaded. Make sure to put all your javascript/jquery code within a `script` tag.

Here is a sample code (in Jquery):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 

    setTimeout(function(){ $("button#join").click(); }, 2000); /* after 2 seconds */

});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the help, where exactly am I putting this? I did place it in the index.html file, still it does not submit the join-button.

Comment: Put it within your html code, preferable just before the closing body tag. We put scripts at the bottom of a web page to improve the page's load time since scripts might take a longer time to load and a user expects to see something come up on their web browser as soon as possible.

Comment: Also you will have to include Jquery in your page. See this link from w3schools: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp

Comment: Thanks alot for the help, I did paste it within the body tags, but no respons, I uploaded the code to pastebin, http://pastebin.com/Enq87t6u

Comment: Issue was setTimeout, setTimeOut!

Comment: yeah, sorry. Must be when I was typing it. It was cased improperly.